# Microphone with XLR adapter won't work in my mixer

Tags: microphone, mixer

I have a headset mic with stereo connector into a Rode VXLR adapter going into my mixer. But the mixer is not picking up anything. The mic works fine on my PC.

I guess the Rhode does not do stereo to mono conversion (spec page is very bare http://www.rode.com/accessories/vxlr) but this page says it does https://www.gear4music.com/PA-DJ-and-Lighting/Rode-VXLR-Stereo-35mm-Mini-Jack-to-Mono-XLR-Converter-Box-Opened/1WF9?

Answer (score 1):

The principal problem is not mono/stereo but that headset microphones are electret condenser microphones requiring plugin power.  You need the VXLR+ adapter rather than the VXLR adapter for that, and even then it will only work if your mixer provides phantom power (usually +48V, there may be a switch for that).

A headset microphone is not likely a stereo microphone.  But it could be a combination TRRS plug combining mono microphone and stereo headphone signals in which case you'll need another (cheap passive) adapter for splitting the microphone signal off.

Comment: ah OK, my mixer can supply phantom power so will try the VXLR+. It does have TRRS but can with a headphone + mic splitter,

Comment: do PC mic ports provide power then?

Comment: and does the VXLR+ do stereo to mono conversion?

Comment: You will need to look at what your mic requires, @GodAtum